# Checking every character to the string via function! but I could not get "s", "i", "e" string true when I check

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
        '''
    char: a single character
    aStr: an alphabetized string

returns: True if char is in aStr; False otherwise
'''
# Your code here
if aStr == "":
    return False;
elif len(aStr) == 1 and  aStr!= char:
    return False;
elif len(aStr) == 1 and  aStr == char:
    return True;     
elif aStr[(len(aStr)//2)] == char:
    return True;
else:
    # if char < aStr[(len(aStr)//2)]:
    return isIn(char, aStr[:(len(aStr)//2)])
    return isIn(char, aStr[(len(aStr)//2):])    


print(isIn("s", "frostbite"))
```

Comment: I am getting true except "s","i", and "e".

Comment: Without reading over all of your code, your problem is most likely that you have two `return` statements in a row. The first one returns either True or False, and then the second one never gets to run at all. You probably wanted something like `return isIn(char, …) or isIn(char, …)`.

Comment: Hey there. What are you trying to accomplish? If you want to know whether a char is in a string, you could use just `'s' in 'frostbyte'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is *almost* correct, but you have one problem:

```
else:
    # if char < aStr[(len(aStr)//2)]:
    return isIn(char, aStr[:(len(aStr)//2)])
    return isIn(char, aStr[(len(aStr)//2):])
```

That first `return` is going to exit the function, returning either `True` or `False`, so that second one will never get called at all.

If you trace through it by adding a `print(char, aStr)` at the start of the function, or using a breakpoint in your debugger (you really should try at least one of these two), you'll see that this is exactly the problem. With `s`, `i`, and `e`, that second `isIn(char, aStr[(len(aStr)//2):])` would have returned `True`, but you never call it.

S, you want to return `True` if either one returns `True`, and `False` if both return `False`. The easy way to do that is to use `or`, exactly the same way you would in English:

```
else:
    # if char < aStr[(len(aStr)//2)]:
    return isIn(char, aStr[:(len(aStr)//2)]) or isIn(char, aStr[(len(aStr)//2):])
```

With that change, your function now correctly finds every letter in `'frostbite'`.